# How come $\exp(-ix)=sin(x)$, since it seems not to correspond to the Euler formula?

Tags: calculus

Here is some context for a better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Who says $\exp(-ix) = \sin x$? I don't see that in your screenshot.

Comment: Since $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$, $e^{-ix} = \cos x - i\sin x$. If you solve for $\sin x$, you obtain $$\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

Comment: Yes but since $\exp(-iw_d)t=sin(w_d*t)$ it is necessarily implied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we find that solutions of a certain equation all have the form $$f(t) = ae^{it} + be^{-it}$$ for any constants $a$ and $b$.  That is, solutions of the equation are linear combinations of the basic solutions $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$.

Expanding $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$ via Euler's theorem, we have  $$\begin{align}
f(t) & = (a\cos t + ai\sin t) + (b\cos t - bi\sin t) \\
& = (a+b) \cos t + (a-b)i\sin t \\
& = a'\cos t + b'\sin t
\end{align}$$

where $a' = a+b$ and $b' = (a-b)i$.

Then we can observe the following:

1. The space of solutions for $f(t)$ is a two-dimensional vector space with basis functions $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$.
2. $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are *also* possible solutions for $f$ (For example, $\cos t = \frac12e^{it} + \frac12e^{-it}$.)
3. $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are linearly independent (because we do not have $\cos t = k\sin t $ for any constant $k$)
4. Therefore, $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ *also* form a basis for the same vector space
5. Therefore, any solution can *also* be written in the form $a'\cos t + b'\sin t$ for some constants $a'$ and $b'$
6. These $a'$ and $b'$ can be calculated from $a$ and $b$, or vice versa, using the usual methods for changing the basis of a vector space.
7. However, in general we do *not* have $a'=a$ or $b'=b$.
8. If we want to consider real-valued solutions, the original form is less convenient; we get a real solution exactly when $a-b$ is pure imaginary.  But in the $a'\cos t + b'\sin t$ form, we get a real solution exactly for any real $a$ and $b$.

This is what is happening in your screenshot.